# как в MySQL преобразовать текстовые значения в колонке в дату?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, дата, datetime

Подскажите пжл возможно ли текстовые данные в столбце `date` заменить на тип данных DATE?
имеется табл. с колонками `id`, `price`, `date` типа TEXT

```
'1234519', '378.00', '01.01.2016'
'1234522', '595.00', '01.01.2016'
'1234525', '77.00', '01.01.2016'
```

Испробовала множество вариантов, вот несколько из них, но ни один не подходит, т.к. программа почему-то считает, что первое число это год, затем месяц и день и в итоге получается дата 01.01.2001

`SELECT *, format(date, 'dd-mm-yyyy') as date FROM table;` 
`SELECT *, format(date, '%d-%m-%Y') as date FROM table;`
`select convert(TEXT, date, 105)) FROM table`
`select *,  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(str_to_date(date, '%d-%m-%Y')) from table`

Comment: [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date). Ну и строку формата для парсинга нужно правильную использовать.

Comment: STR_TO_DATE(). тоже пробовала, но ставила дефис вместо точек. Сейчас все получилось, спасибо